# bytes must be in range(0, 256)

Tags: python-3.x

I am a newbie in python.  I want to initialize crc_table variable with a list of 16 bits data and I don't know do it. When I tried writing like this:

```
crc_table= bytes([0x0000, 0xC0C1, 0xC181, 0x0140, 0xC301, 0x03C0, 0x0280, 0xC241})
```

I am getting "ValueError: bytes must be in range(0, 256)"

Comment: You can create a numpy array with `dtype=np.uint16` if you want to store unsigned 16 bit vectors.

Comment: Range of bytes is 0 to 255. Use numpy > uint16 or struct pack "h" > struct unpack "H". Or just keep int array with proper modulo arithmetic if it solves your purpose.